# Trying to upload gz file to Gitlab through the Python Gitlab api

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab

I'm trying to upload a .gz file to gitlab through the python gitlab api. However, the only documentation I have found to do so is through create file.

https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html#id7

I have tried with my gz file however, the error code I get is 
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`

```
f = project.files.create({'file_path': 'testfile.txt',
                          'branch': 'master',
                          'content': file_content,
                          'author_email': 'test@example.com',
                          'author_name': 'yourname',
                          'commit_message': 'Create testfile'})
```

My expected results would be being able to upload a gz file into Gitlab through the API or other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using paramiko and connecting through that library. I ended up using ssh.exec_command and typed all my commands followed by a \n in order to work around this issue.